# What's the difference between a Portable VM and live USB?

Tags: virtualbox, usb-drive

What is the difference (with pros and cons), if any, between having a portable virtual machine installed on a USB drive then installing an OS using the VM, and just installing the OS directly onto the USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virtual machine's performance is better when it is run from a hard drive than from a USB drive due to much less latency, especially if the hard drive is an SSD. The poor performance of running a virtual machine from a USB drive manifests itself as dimmed or gray screen windows of open applications that take a long time to respond. Frequent lagging by itself can cause a virtual machine to be worthless. The good performance of running a virtual machine from an SSD manifests itself itself as performance almost as quick as running the operating system on a physical machine, assuming that the virtual machine has been configured optimally.

Comment: So, for speeds sake, it would be best to install the OS directly to the USB, rather than going through a VM?
Also, what about for anonymity?

Comment: On my computer, running a virtual machine from an SSD is very fast and much more convenient, so I prefer to run other operating systems as guest OSs in virtual machines rather than running them live from a USB flash drive. I only use USB flash drives for Linux OS installation media, rescue disks, live disk cloning tools, and live disk partitioning tools.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much! My main reason for asking is I would like the extra layer of security/anonymity that the USB would give (say for example when using TAILS), but I didn't know whether installing a VM on the USB, then the OS onto that would be redundant.

Comment: @Richard: Depends on the performance of the USB flash drive. Some are very much better than others. The main performance element is IOPS for  random read/write 4 KiB; anything over 50 is tolerable, over 100 is splendid, less than 25 is terrible for use as a VM or directly installed OS.

Comment: Tails will lag a bit on any device because it uses Tor, but Tor's performance on a physical machine  is bearable in my experience. On the other hand, it costs you nothing to test drive Tails on a USB flash drive before you make up your mind.

Answer (score 1):

Running in a virtual machine will be slower than running the same system directly on the computer hardware. But it might work well enough.

If you connect a USB 3 SSD to a USB 3 port of the computer, the performance will be quite good. I have two such systems,

- an installed Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS host system with Windows 10 in VirtualBox,
- a persistent live Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS host system with Windows 10 in VirtualBox.

I think both systems work rather well in a three year old Toshiba laptop with Intel i5 and built-in Intel graphics. I made these systems to evaluate methods to get a portable Windows system.

---

The memory hardware in a USB pendrive is slower than in an SSD, and often even slower than the USB 2 communication, but there are huge differences. If you want speed, search for a fast USB 3 pendrive. See this link and links from it,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Notes_about_speed)